# Why am I getting garbage output for the first few strings?

Tags: c, pointers

I am fairly new to programming, so please go easy on me. I'm working on extracting words from a sentence using C, and I used double pointers for this. I initially printed the contents of wordArr and it looked fine within the getWords function, but when the array is passed over to main, the first few strings become garbage. Can you please point out where I went wrong? I already tried looking for fixes here in SO, but so far nothing's been working for me..

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 255

int getWords ( char ** wordArr )
{
    size_t charCtr = 0, senSize = MAX_SIZE;
    char * sentence = (char *) malloc (senSize * sizeof(char));
    memset(sentence, '0', senSize);
    int ctr = 0;
    char * word = (char *) malloc (senSize * sizeof(char));
    memset(word, '0', senSize);
    char * endPtr = &word[0];

    charCtr = getdelim( &sentence, &senSize, '\n', stdin );

    if ( sentence[charCtr-1] == '\n' )
        sentence[charCtr-1] = '\0';

    word = strtok( sentence, " " );
    if ( word == NULL || charCtr == 1 )
    {
        printf("No input detected. Exiting...");
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        while ( word != NULL )
        {
            wordArr[ctr] = word;
            ctr++;
            word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    free(sentence);
    free(word);
    return ctr;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int arrSize = 0;
    char * word = (char *) malloc (MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char));
    memset(word, '0', 255);

    char ** wordArr = malloc (sizeof(char*));
    for ( int ctr = 0; ctr < MAX_SIZE; ctr++ )
    {
        wordArr[ctr] = malloc( MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char));
        memset(wordArr[ctr], '0', MAX_SIZE);
    }

    printf("\nEnter a sentence: ");

    arrSize = getWords( wordArr );
    printf("\n\n");

    for ( int ctr = 0; ctr < arrSize; ctr++ )
    {
        printf("\nwordArr[%d]: %s", ctr, wordArr[ctr]);
        printf("\nsize: %zu", strlen(wordArr[ctr]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Depending on your code, I think 'wordArr' may be allocated with memory sizeof(char*) × MAX_SIZE.

Comment: `char ** wordArr = malloc (sizeof(char*));`. That only allocates an array of `1` entry. You need an entry for every word. So it needs to be `malloc (MAX_SIZE*sizeof(char*))`

Comment: @kaylum I was aiming for a string array with only just one row, hence the lacking MAX_SIZE. I tried your suggestion, anyway, but it still outputs garbage values..

Comment: But that's not what your `for` loop in `main` does. It accesses `MAX_SIZE` elements in the array. Which means it is writing to invalid memory resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: In the function `getWords()` you are assigning `word` a lot of different pointers, copying some of them into your array of pointers `wordArr`, overriding what is stored there, and finally freeing some thing you didn't allocate. -- I think you should re-think `wordArr[ctr] = word;`: Do you mean to copy the string? Then *copy* it. ;-) Oh, and BTW: Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Anyway, you did it much better than most newbies on SO.